# Validation not work in kendo grid batch editing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

Hi I am using kendo drop down as a editor template in a grid it works fine but if no value is selected from drop down and I click on add new then it doesn't show an error in the grid and add new row to the grid ... my validation does not work

This is my grid code:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.PrevilegeViewModels)
              .Name("PrevilegeViewModels")
              .ToolBar(tools => tools.Create().Text("Add new product"))
              .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell).CreateAt(GridInsertRowPosition.Bottom))
              .Columns(columns =>
              {
                  columns.Bound(p => p.Table_ID).ClientTemplate("#= Table_ID #" +
                  "<input type='hidden' name='PrevilegeViewModels[#= index(data)#].Table_ID' value='#= Table_ID #' />"
                  ).EditorTemplateName("Table").Title("Table").Width(300);

                columns.Bound(p => p.P_Add).Title("ADD").ClientTemplate("#= P_Add #" +
                    "<input type='hidden' name='PrevilegeViewModels[#= index(data)#].P_Add' value='#= P_Add #' />"
                  ).Width(150);
                  columns.Bound(p => p.P_Delete).Title("DELETE").ClientTemplate("#= P_Delete #" +
                    "<input type='hidden' name='PrevilegeViewModels[#= index(data)#].P_Delete' value='#= P_Delete #' />"
                  ).Width(150);
                  columns.Bound(p => p.P_Edit).Title("EDIT").ClientTemplate("#= P_Edit #" +
                    "<input type='hidden' name='PrevilegeViewModels[#= index(data)#].P_Edit' value='#= P_Edit #' />"
                  ).Width(150);
                  columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(100);
              })
              .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource.Ajax()
                   .Model(model =>
                   {
                       model.Id(p => p.Previleges_ID);
                       model.Field(p => p.Previleges_ID).Editable(false);
                   })
                   .ServerOperation(false)
              )
        )
```

and this is my editor Template ( drop down )

```
@using System.Collections

@model System.Int32
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
          .Name("Table_ID")
          .OptionLabel("---Select---")
          .DataTextField("TableName")
          .DataValueField("ID")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:300px" })
          .Filter(FilterType.StartsWith)
          .DataSource(source =>
          {
              source.Read(read =>
              {
                  read.Action("GetTable", "Privilege");
              })
              .ServerFiltering(true);
          })
```

That is my model

```
public class PrevilegeViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int Previleges_ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Range(1,UInt32.MaxValue)]
        public int Table_ID { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool P_Add { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool P_Edit { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public bool P_Delete { get; set; }        
    }
```

I want that if I do not select any value in the drop down it doesn't take zero and doesn't add a new row .. provide a validation error.

I'm also attached the UI picture. Please guide me ....!

[image]